# How can I preview my Ionic App on Cloud9?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-cloud9

I want to preview my Ionic App on AWS Cloud9 and it doesn't seem to display.

I've tried using ionic serve --port 8080 (because cloud9 only has port 8080 open) and it just seems to show old content from earlier builds.
I've also tried ionic build and then used http-server www to serve from the www output and no avail.

ionic serve --port 8080
ionic build && http-server www

It doesn't display anything in the preview window. I was able to get preview to work with http-server, serving static files but not with ionic serve (or even ng serve).

Answer (score -1):

I solved this and it works awesomely. It wasn't even that hard. AWS Cloud9 is a great platform. Thanks, Me.